# Listen Notifications sent from objective c in javascript environment

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview, webkit

I'm creating a cocoa-app using webkit, which needs communication between Objective-c and JavaScript. After reading apple documentation, i am able to communicate between Objective-C and Javascript.

But i wonder if, there a way to subscribe to listen Notifications sent using `NSNoficationCenter`in javascript. I want objective-c to publish some notifications and javascript to subscribe only for notifications which it wants to receive.

Also if possible this publish/subscribe modal can work in other direction i.e javascript publishes and objective-c listens?